# How to log Firebase Analytics events in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I want to log Firebase event in Flutter, but I cannot log any event.
I want to count what times events are done, so when tapping the button, I log the event.

```
class Onboarding extends StatefulWidget {
  Onboarding({Key key, this.analytics, this.observer})
      : super(key: key);

  final FirebaseAnalytics analytics;
  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer;

  @override
  _OnboardingState createState() => _OnboardingState(analytics, observer);
}
```

```
class _OnboardingState extends State<Onboarding> {
  _OnboardingState(this.analytics, this.observer);
  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer;
  final FirebaseAnalytics analytics;

...
  Future<void> _sendAnalyticsEvent(FirebaseAnalytics analytics, 
FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer) async {
    await analytics.logEvent(
      name: 'onboarding'
    );
  }

  Materialbotton(
    child: onPressed: () async {
    _sendAnalyticsEvent(analytics, observer);
    ...
    }
  )
```

However, if I see Firebase console, I see nothing

Comment: Just for testing try "select_content" instead of "onboarding". In my opinion, it should not take more than 5 minutes to reflect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my understanding, it takes 24 hours in general to see the events logged in firebase console. But to see if the events are indeed being logged, you can use `debugView`, located under `Analytics` sidebar in firebase console.

[image]

Before you could use `debugView`, you'll need to configure the setting by enabling respective emulator or simulator on which you're running the app, as explained [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7201382?hl=en&utm_id=ad)

Once you enable it, you should be able to see the events being logged as you perform action in the app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any way to do this on a physical device? We have an internal test lane for an app and we're trying to get remote logging of a device that is running into issues with the app. This stakeholder is non-technical and we were hoping to just throw logs into Analytics and get on with our lives. Any insights?

Comment: The link does not work